# Retrieve data only show first letter

Tags: php, mysql

I able to retrieve data from my database but it only show one word for each table. In my database, the type is varchar with size 100. here is my code

```
 <?php
 $profile=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE category='$_POST[edit_id]'");

 if($profile)
 {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($profile);
echo $row['description']. "" ;

echo "
<form name='custform' action='2.7update.php' method='POST'>
    <center>
        <table border=1 class='table_common'>
        <tr><td>
            <h2>Championship</h2>
            <table border=0>

            <td><input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value=".$row['id']."></td>


            <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='category' id='category' value=".$row['category']."></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='description' id='description' value=".$row['description']."></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='date' name='date' id='date' value=".$row['date']."></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='status' id='status' value=".$row['status']."></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
            <td colspan=3 align=center>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit_update' value='Confirm and submit'>
            <input type='button' name='back' id='back' value='Back' onClick='javascript:document.location.href=&#39;2.5vieweditchampion.php&#39;;'>
            <input type='button' name='Main Menu' id='Mainmenu' value='Main Menu' 

 onClick='javascript:document.location.href=&#39;2.2coachmain.php&#39;;'>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
    <BR>
</center>
</form>";
 }
 else
 echo "".mysql_error();

 ?>
```

How can i retrieve full sentence instead just showing one word?

Comment: I don't see anything that would truncate your DB information. Tell us more about your database and why you think it is being truncated.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: var_dump($row) and show us the result.

Comment: When i open it, it only show the word "north" instead "north pole"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an HTML error. After processing, your input will look like:

```
<input type='text' name='description' id='description' value=This is a long string>
```

That will only those This. You need quotes:

```
<input type='text' name='description' id='description' value='This is a long string'>
```

You are apparently confused because  you thought the " was the quotes. That ends the string for concatenation. You need more quotes.

```
<td><input type='text' name='description' id='description' value='".$row['description']."'></td>
```